# Mongodb C# driver ignore Null and Empty Lists (ToBsonDocument)

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, bson

```cs
ConventionRegistry.Register("IgnoreIfDefault", 
                            new ConventionPack { new IgnoreIfDefaultConvention(true) }, 
                            _ => true);

var bsonDocument = anon.ToBsonDocument();
```

using IgnoreIfDefaultConvention can cause an unintended behavior due to the fact it affects all default values. For instance, values, as listed below, will not be saved:

```cs
int = 0
decimal = 0
bool = false
```

If I want to ignore only **null values and Empty Arrays** what is the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't use it my own, but I think the answer is this convention: `IgnoreIfNullConvention`. Also you may configure a particular convention for a particular field:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<test>(c => c.MapField(e => e.A).SetIgnoreIfNull(ignoreIfNull: true));
```

or use this attribute `BsonIgnoreIfNullAttribute`

**UPDATE:**
If you need more complicated convention, you can always implement a custom one: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.12/reference/bson/mapping/conventions/

Comment: thanks for the reply. I don't have a separate class and that's why I can not use attributes and RegisterClassMap. the goal is to convert dynamic or anonymous objects to BsonDocument also exclude null and empty lists.

Comment: `IgnoreIfNullConvention`  doesn't ignore empty lists

Comment: `doesn't ignore empty lists` because it's not null? If you need more complicated convention, you can always implement a custom one: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.12/reference/bson/mapping/conventions/

Comment: looks like this is what I need `Custom Conventions`. 
I'll try to write my own custom convention. just update your answer like your last comment (if you want) I will accept that.
if not I will post the custom convention later.
thanks